# ORA-00972: слишком длинный идентификатор

Tags: plsql

Привет. Знаю что эта ошибка говорит о наличии идентификаторов более 30 символов.
Но вот запрос. Здесь нет таких длинных имен. Однако oracle ругается. Подскажите, почему?

```
select Distinct
CS.DG_CODETOFK as "Код ТОФК",
CS.DG_CODEGRBSPPP as "Код ГРБС",
CS.DG_NUMBERACCOUNT as "Номер лицевого счета",
CS.IB_NUMBERBO as "Номер БО", 
CS.UN_REESNUM as "Номер РеесЗапис",
CS.DA_ROOMACT as "Номер договора",
CS.DA_DATECONTRACT as "Дата соглаш",
PL.inn as "ИНН",
PL.kpp as "КПП",
PL.CODECOMPOSITE as "Код СвР",
CS.DA_SUMSUBSRUB as "Сумма Руб",
CS.DA_CODECONTRACT as "Код вида согл МФ",
IB_DATEREGISTRYBO as "Дата постановки",
SBO.APRI_CREATIONDATE as "Дата формирования Сведений БО",
PROT.PI_NUMPROT  as "Номер протокола",
PROT.INF_CREATIONDATE  as "Дата протокола",
PROT.DI_NOTE  as "Причина отказа в протоколе",
IZV.PI_NUMPROT  as "Номер извещения",
IZV.APRI_CREATIONDATE  as "Дата извещения",
AI.INFO_DATEEPBS as "Дата публикации на ЕПБС"

from dc_EXP_SubsidyCurrState CS
inner join dc_EXP_SubsidyAgrmtInfo AI on CS.INFO_GUIDPARENTALDOC = AI.INFO_GUID
inner join DC_EXP_INFBO SBO on AI.INFO_GUID = SBO.SI_GUID_SS
inner join DC_MSC_PROTOCOL PROT on AI.GUID_PROTOKOL = PROT.INF_GUID
inner join DC_EXP_NOTICE_BO IZV on AI.GUIDNOTICE = IZV.APRI_GUID
inner join FS_TABLSUBSID_LIST PL on CS.DOCID = PL.docid
inner join doc d on cs.docid = d.docid
inner join docstate ds on ds.docstateid = d.docstateid
where
  CS.IB_NUMBERBO not like '%TS%' and CS.DG_CODEGRBSPPP not like '501' and
  ds.systemname = 'REGISTRED'
and   CS.DA_DATECONTRACT >= to_date('01.01.2017','dd.mm.yyyy')
order by 1;
```

ORA-00972: слишком длинный идентификатор
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.
Error at Line: 4 Column: 38

Comment: `"Дата формирования Сведений БО"` 30 символов

Comment: @lDrakonl "Дата формирования Сведений БО" - 29 символов. НО 56 байт

Comment: кто то из нас плохо считает. Я 3 раза пересчитал, получается 30

Comment: @lDrakonl Я вставил в редактор, который нумерует позиции. последняя буква в 29, у первой индекс 1. Сейчас пересчитал руками, 29 ... кто то плохо считает ...

Comment: действительно, `select length(..)` дало 29. Пора в отпуск)

Answer (score 4):

Цитата из официальной [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51109):

> Names must be from 1 to 30 bytes long with these exceptions:
>
> - Names of databases are limited to 8 bytes.
> - Names of database links can be as long as 128 bytes.

Обратите внимание, почти везде по непонятным причинам пишут, что ограничение на длину идентификаторов 30 *символов*, но на самом деле ограничение 30 *байт*. А в кодировке UTF-8 русские символы имеют длину 2 байта, таким образом идентификатор в Oracle не может быть длиннее 15 русских букв, в случае если используется кодировка UTF-8.

Comment: я только что попробовал написать 30 русских символов, и у меня не возникло с этим проблем

Comment: @lDrakonl Странно, потому что на моем Oracle 11 после 15 возникли проблемы. У вас какая кодировка БД ?

Comment: `NLS_CHARACTERSET=CL8MSWIN1215`, `NLS_LANGUAGE=ANERICAN`,`NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET=AL16UTF16`

Comment: есть еще параметр `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE`. Из него кажется, что у меня длина тоже должна быть в байтах. Но вот 30 символов  написать получается.

Comment: @lDrakonl Ну вот, у вас виндовая кодировка (1251). В ней конечно русские буквы однобайтовые.

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что для успеха мне надо оформить запрос в кодировке CP-1251? Или это зависит именно от кодировки БД?

Comment: @ИльяБелейчев Думаю это надо проверить  экспериментальным путем. Но по идее да, все что в двойных кавычках Oracle понимает просто как строку неких байт, если вы передадите в кавычках названия в cp1251 то Oracle спокойно это отработает. Вопрос лишь в том, зачем вообще русские названия, если вы их потом автоматом выдаете куда то на вывод, то вероятно получите непонятные иероглифы, если ваш клиент рассчитан на UTF-8

Comment: @Mike Да черт знает этих женщин из отдела тестирования) В любом случае - спасибо!